# Logging windows connections with netsh

Tags: windows, firewall, logging, powershell

I am trying to enable connection logging with `netsh` on Vista x64, as shown in this [MSDN Article about Firewall troubleshooting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb736284%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)...

First, I enabled logging of allowed connections to `%systemroot%\system32\LogFiles\Firewall\pfirewall.log`, below...

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> netsh advfirewall set allprofiles logging allowedconnections enable
Ok.

PS C:\Windows\system32>
```

Next I check whether logging is really enabled. AFAICT, it is...

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> netsh advfirewall show currentprofile

Public Profile Settings:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
State                                 ON
Firewall Policy                       BlockInbound,AllowOutbound
LocalFirewallRules                    N/A (GPO-store only)
LocalConSecRules                      N/A (GPO-store only)
InboundUserNotification               Enable
RemoteManagement                      Disable
UnicastResponseToMulticast            Enable

Logging:
LogAllowedConnections                 Enable
LogDroppedConnections                 Disable
FileName                              %systemroot%\system32\LogFiles\Firewall\pfirewall.log
MaxFileSize                           4096

Ok.

PS C:\Windows\system32>
```

However, when I try to retrieve the log, I can't...

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-Content %systemroot%\system32\LogFiles\Firewall\pfirewall.log
Get-Content : Cannot find path 'C:\Windows\system32\%systemroot%\system32\LogFiles\Firewall\pfi
oes not exist.
At line:1 char:12
+ Get-Content <<<<  %systemroot%\system32\LogFiles\Firewall\pfirewall.log
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Windows\syst...l\pfirewall.log:String) [Get-C
   ception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand
PS C:\Windows\system32>
```

What else do I need to do to enable connection logging from powershell?  I want to avoid rebooting, if at all possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see, your `%systemroot%` variable does not get resolved correctly in PowerShell when you retrieve the logfile: Cannot find path 'C:\Windows\system32\%systemroot%\system32\LogFiles\Firewall\pfioes not exist.

In PowerShell, you access environment variables by doing: `$env:Variable`

Please try this command:

`Get-Content $env:systemroot\system32\LogFiles\Firewall\pfirewall.log`